# Binary Tree to HTML list

Tags: javascript, html, binary-tree

I have a binary tree that I want to convert to a nested HTML unordered list.

I have a function I am trying to modify to do the task.

I am trying the following method (run snippet for output):

This method is in the BinaryTreeClass

```
inOrderTraverseHtml(start = this.rootPtr) {
    if (!start.isLeaf()) 
    {
        this.html+="<ul>"
    }
    else
    {
        this.html+="<li>"
    } // end if
    if (start.getLeftChild() !== null) 
    {
        this.inOrderTraverseHtml(start.getLeftChild());
    }; // end if
    this.html+=`<a href="#">${start.getItem().value}</a>`;
    if (start.getRightChild() !== null) 
    {
        this.inOrderTraverseHtml(start.getRightChild());
    }; // end if
    if (!start.isLeaf()) 
    {
        this.html+="</ul>"
    }
    else
    {
        this.html+="</li>"
    } // end if
} // end inOrderTraverseHtml
```

This does not create a proper list item. I am getting too many `ul` on top.

The snippet contains my full code (contains ES6)

```js
/**
 * This is the Node class
 * Each item has a setter and getter
 */
class Node {
  constructor(item = null, id = null, leftChild = null, rightChild = null) {
    this.id = id;
    this.item = item;
    this.leftChildPtr = leftChild;
    this.rightChildPtr = rightChild;
  }
  setItem(item) {
    this.item = item;
  }
  getItem() {
    return this.item;
  }
  setId(id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  getId() {
    return this.id;
  }
  isLeaf() {
    return this.leftChildPtr === null && this.rightChildPtr === null;
  }
  getLeftChild() {
    return this.leftChildPtr;
  }
  getRightChild() {
    return this.rightChildPtr;
  }
  setRightChild(rightPtr) {
    this.rightChildPtr = rightPtr;
  }
  setLeftChild(leftPtr) {
    this.leftChildPtr = leftPtr;
  }
}
/**
 * This is the MathModel class
 * Each item has a setter and getter
 * This gets inserted into the nodes
 */
class MathModel {
  constructor(type = "Operator", value = "+") {
    this.type = type;
    this.value = value;
  }
  Type() {
    return this.type;
  }
  setType(new_type) {
    this.type = new_type;
  }
  Value() {
    return this.value;
  }
  setValue(new_value) {
    this.value = new_value;
  }
}
/**
 * This is the BinaryNodeTree class
 * This is an ADT for a unbalenced binary tree
 * The ids for nodes will be phased out or at least be given a better index 
 * for now I used it for an html canvas 
 */
class BinaryNodeTree {
  constructor() {
    this.rootPtr = null;
    this.idRange = [
      "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z",
      "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z",
      "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"
    ]
    this.ids = [];
    this.output = "";
    this.html = "";
  }
  setRoot(type, value) {
    let id = this.createId();
    this.ids.push(id);
    let newNode = new Node(new MathModel(type, value), id);
    this.rootPtr = newNode;
  }
  getRoot() {
    return this.rootPtr;
  }
  createId(len = 6) {
    let string = "";
    const rangeLength = this.idRange.length;
    for (let i = len; i--;) {
      string += this.idRange[Math.floor(Math.random() * rangeLength)]
    }
    return string;
  } // createId
  getHeightHelper(subTreePtr = new Node()) {
    if (subTreePtr === null || subTreePtr === new Node()) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      let a = this.getHeightHelper(subTreePtr.getLeftChild());
      let b = this.getHeightHelper(subTreePtr.getRightChild());
      let max = 0;
      if (a > b) {
        max = a;
      } else {
        max = b;
      }
      return 1 + max;
    }
  } // end getHeightHelper
  getNumberOfNodesHelper(subTreePtr = new Node()) {
    if (subTreePtr === null || subTreePtr === new Node()) {
      return 0;
    } else if (subTreePtr.isLeaf()) {
      return 0;
    } else if (subTreePtr.getLeftChild() === null && subTreePtr.getRightChild() !== null || subTreePtr.getLeftChild() !== null && subTreePtr.getRightChild() === null) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 2;
    }
  } // end getNumberOfNodesHelper
  /**
   * This will be an inorder traverse of the tree to find a node
   * @param {function} cb 
   * @param {Node} treePtr 
   * @param {*} target 
   */
  findNodeInOrder(cb, treePtr = this.rootPtr, targetId) {
    if (treePtr === null) {
      return null;
    } else if (treePtr.id === targetId) {
      return cb(treePtr);
    } else {
      this.findNodeInOrder(cb, treePtr.getLeftChild(), targetId);
      this.findNodeInOrder(cb, treePtr.getRightChild(), targetId);
    }
  } // end findNodeInOrder
  inOrderTraverse(cb, treePtr = this.rootPtr, parent = null) {
    if (treePtr !== null) {
      this.inOrderTraverse(cb, treePtr.getLeftChild(), treePtr);
      let Item = treePtr.getItem();
      cb(Item, treePtr.id, treePtr, parent);
      this.inOrderTraverse(cb, treePtr.getRightChild(), treePtr);
    }
  } // end inOrderTraverse
  toString() {
    this.output = "";
    this.inOrderTraversePrint(this.rootPtr)
    return this.output;
  }
  toHTML() {
    this.html = `<div class="tree">`;
    this.inOrderTraverseHtml(this.rootPtr)
    this.html += "</div>";
    return this.html;
  }
  inOrderTraversePrint(start = this.rootPtr) {
    if (!start.isLeaf()) {
      // console.log("(");
      this.output += "("
    }
    if (start.getLeftChild() !== null) {
      this.inOrderTraversePrint(start.getLeftChild());
    }; // end if
    // console.log(start.getItem().value);
    this.output += start.getItem().value;
    if (start.getRightChild() !== null) {
      this.inOrderTraversePrint(start.getRightChild());
    }; // end if
    if (!start.isLeaf()) {
      //   console.log(")");
      this.output += ")";
    }
  } // end inOrderTraversePrint 
  inOrderTraverseHtml(start = this.rootPtr) {
    if (!start.isLeaf()) {
      this.html += "<ul>"
    } else {
      this.html += "<li>"
    } // end if
    if (start.getLeftChild() !== null) {
      this.inOrderTraverseHtml(start.getLeftChild());
    }; // end if
    this.html += `<a href="#">${start.getItem().value}</a>`;
    if (start.getRightChild() !== null) {
      this.inOrderTraverseHtml(start.getRightChild());
    }; // end if
    if (!start.isLeaf()) {
      this.html += "</ul>"
    } else {
      this.html += "</li>"
    } // end if
  } // end inOrderTraverseHtml  
  preOrderTraverse(cb, treePtr = this.rootPtr) {
    if (treePtr !== null) {
      let Item = treePtr.getItem();
      cb(Item, treePtr.id);
      this.inOrderTraverse(cb, treePtr.getLeftChild());
      this.inOrderTraverse(cb, treePtr.getRightChild());
    }
  } // end preOrderTraverse  
  postOrderTraverse(cb, treePtr = this.rootPtr) {
    if (treePtr !== null) {
      this.inOrderTraverse(cb, treePtr.getLeftChild());
      this.inOrderTraverse(cb, treePtr.getRightChild());
      let Item = treePtr.getItem();
      cb(Item, treePtr.id);
    }
  } // end postOrderTraverse    
  addLeft(treePtr = new Node(), newItem) {
    let id = this.createId();
    while (this.ids.indexOf(id) !== -1) {
      id = this.createId();
    }
    let newNode = new Node(newItem, id);
    if (treePtr.getLeftChild() !== null) {
      let tempPtr = treePtr.getLeftChild();
      newNode.setLeftChild(tempPtr);
      treePtr.setLeftChild(newNode);
    } else {
      treePtr.setLeftChild(newNode);
    }
  } // end addLeft
  addRight(treePtr = new Node(), newItem) {
    let id = this.createId();
    while (this.ids.indexOf(id) !== -1) {
      id = this.createId();
    }
    let newNode = new Node(newItem, id);
    if (treePtr.getRightChild() !== null) {
      let tempPtr = treePtr.getRightChild();
      newNode.setRightChild(tempPtr);
      treePtr.setRightChild(newNode);
    } else {
      treePtr.setRightChild(newNode);
    }
  } //  end addRight
  removeFromIdsHelper(id) {
    let index = this.ids.indexOf(id);
    this.ids.splice(index, 1);
  } // end removeFromIdsHelper
  removeRight(treePtr = new Node(), newItem) {
    this.removeFromIdsHelper(treePtr.getRightChild().id);
    treePtr.setRightChild(null)
    // todo: handle existing nodes in children
  } //  end removeRight
  removeLeft(treePtr = new Node(), newItem) {
    this.removeFromIdsHelper(treePtr.getLeftChild().id);
    treePtr.setLeftChild(null)
    // todo: handle existing nodes in children
  } //  end removeLeft
}

/**
 * This is the implementation of the Abstract data type
 */
let tree = new BinaryNodeTree();

function handleCreateClick() {
  $("[data-action=start]").off().on("click", function() {
    tree.setRoot("Operator", "+");
    tree.addLeft(tree.getRoot(), new MathModel("Operator", "-"))
    tree.addRight(tree.getRoot(), new MathModel("Number", 20))
    tree.addLeft(tree.getRoot().getLeftChild(), new MathModel("Operator", "/"))
    tree.addRight(tree.getRoot().getLeftChild(), new MathModel("Number", 60))
    tree.addLeft(tree.getRoot().getLeftChild().getLeftChild(), new MathModel("Number", 75))
    tree.addRight(tree.getRoot().getLeftChild().getLeftChild(), new MathModel("Number", 60))
    console.log("Tree created", "Uncomment line 299 to log it.");
    // console.log(tree);
  });
}

function handleDrawClick() {
  $("[data-action=draw]").off().on("click", function() {
    console.log(tree.toString());
    $(".output").html(tree.toHTML())
  });
}

function invokes() {
  handleCreateClick();
  handleDrawClick();
}


$(document).ready(() => {
  invokes();
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h1>TREE</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>The Node class starts on line 5</li>
        <li>The Math Model class starts on line 45</li>
        <li>The Binary Tree class starts on line 69
          <ul>
            <li>toHTML() starts on line 168</li>
            <li>toHTML() calls inOrderTraverseHtml() which is on line 182</li>
            <li>This gets called from the implementation on the <span class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Draw</span> event on line 302</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>The implementation of the Abstract data type starts in JS on line 269</li>
        <li>Uncomment line 307 to view the tree</li>
      </ul>
      <h2>To Start</h2>
      <ol>
        <li>Click start</li>
        <li>Click draw</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <div class="btn btn-primary" data-action="start">Start!</div>
        <div class="btn btn-info" data-action="draw">Draw!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="output"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

I am trying to create the markup seen in [this codeplayer tutorial](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree)

**EDIT 2**

I am including an example of how I want the output to look.

```
<div class="tree">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Parent</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Child</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Child</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You might want to (re-?)read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with a focus on "minimal".

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I removed some code.

Comment: I'm afraid that's still too big for me.  How about this?  What's your input look like, and what output are you trying to achieve?  Not your whole app, just your binary tree and what you want to turn it into.

Comment: All the code in the snippet is required to construct the tree. I have removed everything extra.There are three classes (`Node` class, the `Model` class, and the `Binary Tree` Class). After those, I define my click events. The `start click event` creates the tree. The `draw click event` will attempt to make it into a HTML list. The code to convert the tree into html is called `inOrderTraverseHtml()` and is in the `Binary Node Tree` class. The output needed, can be seen in the "This codeplayer tutorial link". The output I am getting is placed on the DOM after draw is clicked.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I just added the markup from the example I shared. This is the type of nesting/output I am going for.

Comment: Is that your own tree implementation or someone else's?  I've rarely seen one that long and involved in JS.

Comment: @ScottSauyet this is my own implementation. It’s based loosely off of my c++ binary search tree. I created my own because I wanted to practice recursion & abstract data types in javascript. Considering JS it single threaded and there are no pointers, I wanted to test the performance difference. Most of the code is simply getters and setters.

Comment: I don't know how that output is supposed to be tied to your binary tree input of `[60, "/", [75, "-", [60, "+", 20]]]`.  First of all, with three grandchildren, it's not a binary tree, so you can't do `inOrder` traversals on it.  Still, there is far too much code to try to make sense of it.

Comment: Well thank you for your input and help. I will continue to look for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been thinking about this problem a bit.  I'm glad you came up with something that works for you.  I still haven't tried to work my way through your code.  There is simply too much there for my limited attention.

But the underlying problem interested me, and I have a very different solution written from scratch.

### A Much Simpler Tree

We start with a much simpler tree structure.

```
const node = (val, left, right) => ({val, left, right})

const preorder = (before, after, node) =>
  [before(node.val)]
  .concat(node.left ? preorder(before, after, node.left) : [])
  .concat(node.right ? preorder(before, after, node.right) : [])
  .concat(after(node.val))
```

The problem seems to require a `preorder` traversal, not an `inorder` one.  If we wanted an `inorder` traversal, it's quite easy:

```
const inorder = (fn, node) => 
  (node.left ? inorder(fn, node.left) : [])
  .concat(fn(node.val))
  .concat(node.right ? inorder(fn, node.right) : [])
```

Note that these traversals simply collect the results of function calls on each node into an array.  To handle the fact that you want HTML nodes wrapping one another in our preorder version, we have separate `before` and `after` functions.  We'll use that in a bit.

A tree built like this can be quite simple:

```
node(
  '+',
  18,
  node('*', 4, 6)
)
```

Which generates an object like this:

```
{
  val: "+",
  left: 18,
  right: {
    val: "*",
    left: 4,
    right: 6
  }
}
```

Or if you like, you could do

```
node(
  node('+'),
  node(18),
  node('*', node(4), node(6))
)
```

which looks more like this:

```
{
  val: {
    val: "+",
    left: undefined,
    right: undefined
  },
  left: {
    val: 18,
    left: undefined,
    right: undefined
  },
  right: {
    val: "*",
    left: {
        val: 4,
        left: undefined,
        right: undefined
    },
    right: {
        val: 6,
        left: undefined,
        right: undefined
    }
  }
}
```

If you are going to do that, you might prefer this slightly more complicated version of `node`:

```
const node = (val, left, right) => 
    Object.assign({val}, left ? {left} : {}, right ? {right} : {})
```

which removes those `undefined`s, leaving you with an output like

```
{
  val: {
    val: "+"
  },
  left: {
    val: 18
  },
  right: {
    val: "*",
    left: {
      val: 4
    },
    right: {
      val: 6
    }
  }
}
```

### Node Types

For this problem, we have two different types of nodes we want to consider, *operators* and *numbers*.  We create two simple functions to wrap those:

```
const operator = (value) => ({type: 'op', value})
const number = (value) => ({type: 'num', value})
```

Note how much simpler these types and the node/tree function above are than your port from an OO language.  Javascript is a somewhat higher level language, and there are many ways in which it can be simpler than Java/C++/C#/etc.

### Sample Data

Using these node types, we can create the tree requested like this:

```
const myTree = node(
  operator('+'),
  node(
    operator('-'), 
    node(
      operator('/'),
      node(number(60)),
      node(number(75)),
    ),
    node(number(60))
  ),
  node(number(20))
)
```

The question has this being built in a more piecemeal fashion.  We could do that as well as we like, accessing nodes via selectors such as `myTree.left.left.right`, and assigning values to their `left`, `right`, and `val` properties.  In any dynamic situation, we might have to do that.  But if we have the whole structure up front, this is much cleaner.

### HTML Generation

Our `preorder` function visits each node twice, once before the children (if any) and once after them.  So I guess it's not truly `preorder`, but a combination of that and `postorder`.  But this works for our use-case, of wanting to do before-and-after HTML snippets.

```
const toHtml = (tree) => `<div class='tree'><ul>` + preorder(
  node => node.type === 'op' 
      ? `<li><a class="${node.type}" href="#">${node.value}</a><ul>` 
      : `<li><a class="${node.type}" href="#">${node.value}</a></li>`,
  node => node.type === 'op' 
      ? `</ul></li>` 
      : ``, 
  tree
).join('') + `</ul></div>`
```

This is very specific to our problem, and it generates the markup in the before and after functions it supplies to `preorder`, joins the resulting array, and wraps that in the `<div>` tag requested.  We add CSS classes to the markup, in case that would help.

### Usage

Putting this all together, we get

```
toHtml(myTree)
```

which will generate something like

```
<div class='tree'>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="op" href="#">+</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a class="op" href="#">-</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a class="op" href="#">/</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a class="num" href="#">60</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a class="num" href="#">75</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li> 
              <a class="num" href="#">60</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="num" href="#">20</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

(although without the fancy indentation.)

### Demo

We can see how this all works together in this snippet:

```js
// Binary Tree Implementation

const node = (val, left, right) => ({val, left, right})

const preorder = (before, after, node) =>
  [before(node.val)]
  .concat(node.left ? preorder(before, after, node.left) : [])
  .concat(node.right ? preorder(before, after, node.right) : [])
  .concat(after(node.val))


// Node types

const operator = (value) => ({type: 'op', value})
const number = (value) => ({type: 'num', value})


// HTML Generation

const toHtml = (tree) => `<div class='tree'><ul>` + preorder(
  node => node.type === 'op' 
      ? `<li><a class="${node.type}" href="#">${node.value}</a><ul>` 
      : `<li><a class="${node.type}" href="#">${node.value}</a></li>`,
  node => node.type === 'op' 
      ? `</ul></li>` 
      : ``, 
  tree
).join('') + `</ul></div>`


// Sample Data

const myTree = node(
  operator('+'),
  node(
    operator('-'), 
    node(
      operator('/'),
      node(number(60)),
      node(number(75)),
    ),
    node(number(60))
  ),
  node(number(20))
)


// Usage

console.log(toHtml(myTree))
```

### Summary

This does not answer your basic question about why your code wasn't working, but it offers what I think is a simpler solution to dealing with trees in Javascript, and creates a means to build the output you're looking for out of one.

Javascript is at least as much a functional language as it is an Object-Oriented one.  The techniques here are reasonably functional, working with simple, pure functions.  I believe they produce a much cleaner program.

Comment: Very nice implementation. I do like how you defined the model using the arrow functions. Your implementation also returns a string of html where mine uses DOM manipulation. Yours is way more abstract than mine! Goodjob! Thank you for all the hard work on this. I am glad my question was able to motivate some creative thinking. If you want to understand my implementation better, please read "Data Abstraction & Problem Solving with C++" by Frank M. Carrano. Chapter 16 & 17 specifically.

Answer (score 1):

So I added a class extension to the BinaryNodeTree. It is below and works as I needed it to.

```
class BinaryNodeTreeToHTML extends BinaryNodeTree {
    constructor(rootPtr, className = "tree-html") {
        super(rootPtr);
        this.html = [];
        this.rootPtr = rootPtr;
        this.className = className;
    }
    createContainer() {
        const _ = this;
        return new $("<div />", {
            "class": _.className
        });
    }
    createListItem(type, value, id, parentId) {
        const _ = this;
        return $("<li />", {
            id,
            "data-parent_id": parentId,
            "data-type": type,
            "data-value": value,
            html: _.createAnchor(type, value)
        });
    }
    createAnchor(type, value) {
        return $("<a />", {
            href: "#",
            "data-type": type,
            text: value
        });
    }
    createUnorderedList(parent = "root") {
        return $("<ul />", {
            "data-parent": parent
        })
    }
    Start(outputClassName) {
        const _ = this;
        console.log(this.Root);
        const $output = $(`.${outputClassName}`).eq(0);
        const $container = this.createContainer();
        let $main_ul = _.createUnorderedList();
        $container.append($main_ul);
        $output.append($container);
        console.log(_.html);
        this.inOrderTraverse((Item, Id, Pointer, Parent) => {
            if (Parent !== null) {
                let $new_item = _.createListItem(Item.Type, Item.Value, Id, Parent.Id);
                $main_ul.append($new_item);
            } else {
                let $new_item = _.createListItem(Item.Type, Item.Value, Id, "root");
                $main_ul.append($new_item);
            }
        })
        for(let obj of $main_ul.find("li")){
            let $obj = $(obj);
            if($obj.data().parent_id !== "root"){
                let $parent = $("#"+$obj.data().parent_id);
                if($parent.find("[data-parent="+$parent.attr("id")+"]").length > 0){
                    let $ul = $parent.find("[data-parent="+$parent.attr("id")+"]")
                    $ul.append($obj);
                }else{
                    $parent.append(_.createUnorderedList($parent.attr("id")).append($obj))
                }
            }

        }

        return $container;
    }
};
```